# Python groupby function not recognising that there are keys that are identical that can be "grouped on"

Tags: python, group-by

I have a list which I am trying to group by the first element of the nested list. The problem is that my code is not recognising that there are only 5 different values among the grouped on element.

```
a = [['2.25.151989603747108360484758994222924880510', 1],
['2.25.23907329898781253437777953862543062317', 1],
['2.25.151989603747108360484758994222924880510', 2],
['2.25.23907329898781253437777953862543062317', 1],
['2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925', 1],
['2.25.339018106044083012102817776589396922392', 1],
['2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925', 1],
['2.25.23907329898781253437777953862543062317', 1],
['2.25.151989603747108360484758994222924880510', 1],
['2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925', 1],
['2.25.151989603747108360484758994222924880510', 1],
['2.25.339018106044083012102817776589396922392', 1],
['2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925', 1],
['2.25.151989603747108360484758994222924880510', 1],
['2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925', 1],
['2.25.339018106044083012102817776589396922392', 1],
['2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925', 1]]
```

Just as a simple test, I have run (thinking there may be something odd about the variable I'm grouping on:

```
for key, group in groupby(a, lambda x: str(x[0]).strip()):
     print(key)
```

I get this:

```
2.25.151989603747108360484758994222924880510
2.25.23907329898781253437777953862543062317
2.25.151989603747108360484758994222924880510
2.25.23907329898781253437777953862543062317
2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925
2.25.339018106044083012102817776589396922392
2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925
2.25.23907329898781253437777953862543062317
2.25.151989603747108360484758994222924880510
2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925
2.25.151989603747108360484758994222924880510
2.25.339018106044083012102817776589396922392
2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925
2.25.151989603747108360484758994222924880510
2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925
```

If I do this:

```
r=[]
for m in a:
    for n in a:
        if m[0]==n[0]:
            r.append(m[0])
                     
set(r)
```

I get this

```
{'2.25.105201430514553352325644071061576888668',
 '2.25.151989603747108360484758994222924880510',
 '2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925',
 '2.25.23907329898781253437777953862543062317',
 '2.25.339018106044083012102817776589396922392'}
```

Which is correct. Why isn't the groupby function working?

Comment: Read the docs. List must be sorted first.

Comment: Well, `itertools.groupby` didn't behave as you expected, so it would have made sense to look at its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to find "Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function" at the end of first paragraph and the second paragraph explaining this in more detail. By the way: I didn't downvote your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It groups by [consecutive keys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), not all key of a kind, as in SQL:

> Make an iterator that returns **consecutive** keys and groups from the iterable.

If you sort the keys first it will work as you expect:

```py
key = lambda x: str(x[0]).strip()
for key, group in groupby(sorted(a, key=key), key=key):
    print(key)
```

Output:

```
2.25.151989603747108360484758994222924880510
2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925
2.25.23907329898781253437777953862543062317
2.25.339018106044083012102817776589396922392
```

Answer (score 1):

`groupby` combines **consecutive** keys that are identical.  So the order is important.   You would have to sort the data before using groupby to get the expected result:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: str(x[0]).strip())
for key, group in groupby(a, lambda x: str(x[0]).strip()):
    print(key)
```

If you are only looking for the distinct keys, you don't need groupby at all.  Just create a dictionary:

```
list(dict(a).keys())

['2.25.151989603747108360484758994222924880510', 
 '2.25.23907329898781253437777953862543062317', 
 '2.25.159215431212584126451402597802236328925', 
 '2.25.339018106044083012102817776589396922392']
```